# Why does the Torah not write about or mention the creation of the Angels/Melachim? When were they made?

Tags: parashat-bereishit, creation, malach-angel

It's something I've interested in for a while ;)
Thank you!

Comment: What I've learned is that the written torah is focused on the human story on earth and so only alludes to the celestial worlds when it says in genesis that god created the heavens and the earth. there are texts in the oral torah which describe the spiritual realms in detail, such as the Zohar and other kabbalistic texts.

Answer (score 6):

Several commentators see an allusion to the creation of the malakhim in Genesis 2:1 ( וַיְכֻלּוּ הַשָּׁמַיִם וְהָאָרֶץ וְכָל-צְבָאָם). For example, the Ramban on the word צְבָאָם writes:

> **והנה בכאן רמז על יצירת המלאכים**

> *and there is a hint here to the formation of the malakhim.*

Genesis Rabbah 3:8 records different opinions concerning which day of creation the malakhim were created on:

> רַבִּי יוֹחָנָן אָמַר בַּשֵּׁנִי נִבְרְאוּ הַמַּלְאָכִים, הֲדָא הוּא דִכְתִיב (תהלים קד, ג): הַמְקָרֶה בַמַּיִם עֲלִיּוֹתָיו הַשָֹּׂם עָבִים רְכוּבוֹ הַמְהַלֵּךְ עַל כַּנְפֵי רוּחַ, וּכְתִיב (תהלים קד, ד): עֹשֶׂה מַלְאָכָיו רוּחוֹת. רַבִּי חֲנִינָא אָמַר בַּחֲמִישִׁי נִבְרְאוּ מַלְאָכִים, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (בראשית א, כ): וְעוֹף יְעוֹפֵף עַל הָאָרֶץ, וּכְתִיב (ישעיה ו, ב): וּבִשְׁתַּיִם יְעוֹפֵף. רַבִּי לוּלִיאָנִי בַּר טַבְרָאִי בְּשֵׁם רַבִּי יִצְחָק אָמַר, בֵּין עַל דַּעְתֵּיהּ דְּרַבִּי חֲנִינָא בֵּין עַל דַּעְתֵּיהּ דְּרַבִּי יוֹחָנָן הַכֹּל מוֹדִים שֶׁלֹא נִבְרָא בַּיּוֹם הָרִאשׁוֹן כְּלוּם, שֶׁלֹא תֹאמַר מִיכָאֵל הָיָה מוֹתֵחַ בִּדְרוֹמוֹ שֶׁל רָקִיעַ, וְגַבְרִיאֵל בִּצְפוֹנוֹ, וְהַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא מְמַדֵּד בְּאֶמְצָעִיתוֹ, אֶלָּא (ישעיה מד, כד): אָנֹכִי ד' עֹשֶׂה כֹּל נֹטֶה שָׁמַיִם לְבַדִּי רֹקַע הָאָרֶץ מֵאִתִּי, מִי אִתִּי כְּתִיב, מִי הָיָה שֻׁתָּף עִמִּי בִּבְרִיָּתוֹ שֶׁל עוֹלָם.

> *Rabbi Yohanan said "on the second [day] the angels were created. See! It is written "He lays the beams of his upper chambers in the waters; he makes the clouds his chariot; he walks upon the wings of the wind (Psalm 104:3)" and it is written "he makes the winds his angels (Psalm 104:4)"". Rabbi Hanina said "on the fifth [day] the angels were created, as it is said: "and let fowl fly above the earth (Genesis 1:20)" and it is written "and with two [wings] it flies (Isaiah 6:2)"". Rabbi Lulyani the son of Tavrai in the name of Rabbi Yishaq said: "Whether t is according to the opinion of Rabbi Hanina or according to the opinion of Rabbi Yohanan, everyone agrees that they were not created on the first day, so you cannot say that Michael stretched out the southern section of the firmament, and Gabriel the northern section and the Holy One, blessed be He, measured in the middle. Rather "I am Hashem, that makes all things; that stretched forth the heavens alone; that spread abroad the earth by Myself (meitti). [Read this as if] "who is with me? (mi itti) is written: "who was joined with me in my creation of the universe?""*

I do not believe that we can answer why the Torah does or does not explicitly mention the creation of specific entities in Genesis, particularly those of a metaphysical nature.